# How to calculate the residue of $\frac{z^{2n}+1}{z^n[iaz^2+(1+a^2)z-ia]}$ at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

Could someone give me some pointers how to calculate:

$$\operatorname*{res}_{z=0} \frac{z^{2n}+1}{z^n[iaz^2+(1+a^2)z-ia]}$$

I don't think it's possible using the limit formula, but I'm having problems providing a Laurent-expansion.

**#EDIT**
Given $0<a<1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the fraction into two parts.

$$\frac{z^{2n}}{z^n[iaz^2 + (1+a^2)z - ia]} = \frac{z^n}{iaz + (1+a^2)z - ia}$$

is holomorphic at $0$ for $n > 0$, so that part has residue $0$ at $0$. The other part is best treated by a partial fraction decomposition,

$$\frac{1}{iaz^2 + (1+a^2)z - ia} = \frac{1}{(iaz+1)(z-ia)} = \frac{c_1}{iaz+1} + \frac{c_2}{z-ia},$$

with constants $c_1,c_2$ that are to be determined. Then you can expand both summands into geometric series, and the residue of

$$\frac{1}{z^n[iaz + (1+a^2)z-ia]}$$

at $0$ is the sum of the coefficients of $z^{n-1}$ in the two geometric series.

Comment: You, sir, are awesome

Comment: Hmm this proves more difficult then I thought, especially the second term: $$\frac{c_2}{z-ia} = \frac{ic_2}{a}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{ia}}$$ And this can't be expanded can it? $\left| \frac{z}{ia}\right|$ is not $<1$?

Comment: We're interested in the expansion around $z = 0$, we just want some $\rho > 0$ such that the series converges for $\lvert z\rvert < \rho$. Choosing $\rho = a$ then works, for $\lvert z\rvert < a$, we have $\left\lvert \frac{z}{ia}\right\rvert < 1$.